# How to filter specific array size using project aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this lab test in the mongodb course i am currently taking, the movies collection have a title field and the instruction says:

1. Using only $project aggregation.
2. find the movie titles composed of only 1 word like **"Cinderella"** and **"3-25"** should count where as "Cast Away" would not.
3. Use **$split** String expression and **$size** Array expression.

Here's a sample document from movies collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573a1390f29313caabcd4192"),
    "title" : "The Conjuring of a Woman at the House of Robert Houdin",
    "year" : 1896,
    "runtime" : 1,
    "cast" : [
            "Jeanne d'Alcy",
            "Georges M�li�s"
    ]
}
```

And here's my code:

```
var pipeline = [
    { $project: {
        "title": { $split: ["$title"," "] }
    } },
    { $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "title_size": {$eq: [{$size: "$title"}, 1]},
        "Movie": "$title"
    } }
]

db.movies.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The **$eq** returns boolean values true and false, not what i expected, then i tried the `$literal: 1`as the second expression of $eq but i get the same boolean values

What i wanted to achieved is this:

```
{ "title_size" : 1, "Movie" : [ "Cinderella" ] }
```

But how?

Comment: Are you allow to use `$match`?

Comment: Something like `"title_size": {$cond:[{$eq: [{$size: "$title"}, 1]},{ $literal: 1 }, { $literal: 0}]}`

Comment: [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) does not filter.

Comment: @Alejandro Montilla $match maybe allowed, where shall i put it?

Answer (score 2):

```
[
    {
        $project: {
        splitedTitles: {$split: ["$title", " "]}
        }
    },
    { 
        $match : { splitedTitles : { $size: 1 } }
    } 
]
```